# Open and read certain files in a directory; write all text in those files to cells in a .csv

Tags: python, excel, csv, text

I've read a number of posts that get close to my problem, but I still haven't been able to figure it out so hopefully you all can help me get there!

I have a directory with thousands of subfolders, each with 1-4 files. I need to find all the .txt files (there are thousands), open them, and write the text to individual cells in a .csv.

In each .txt is a single chunk of text (sometimes multiple pages long). I need each chunk of text to occupy a single cell in my .csv.

When I run my code on a test directory (only 10 folders and about 15 .txt files) I get no errors, a .csv is created, but all the cells are empty.

I'm running python 2.7 in aptana studio and I'm a novice so I'm excited for some SO brilliance to bail me out :)

Here is my code so far:

```
import csv
import os

def get_text():
    with open('out.csv','w') as out_file:
        csv_out = csv.writer(out_file, delimiter=',')
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk('/Users//Desktop/TEXT-TEST'):
            for file in files:
                if file.lower().endswith('.txt'):
                    with open(file) as f:
                        csv_out.writerows(f.read())

get_text()
```

Comment: Please see the [help]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this work.

```
import csv
import os

def get_text():
    with open('out.csv','wb') as out_file:   #use 'wb' to prevent extra blank line
        csv_out = csv.writer(out_file, delimiter=',')
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(r'/Users/Desktop/TEXT-TEST'):
            for file in files:
                if file.lower().endswith('.txt'):
                    filepath = os.path.join(root,file)  # You may got an error with out this line
                    with open(filepath, 'r') as f:
                        content = f.read()
                        csv_out.writerow([content])   # change to wirterow

get_text()
```

Comment: That seems to have gotten me much closer! Now I have a massive excel file with 10000+ rows, which is what I expected. However, the text seems to have made its way into the cells idiosyncratically. Some cells have entire paragraphs (what I want), but many cells have only a few words and some have just a character or two. On top of that, most of the text is in column a, but some rows have text in columns b through e. Ideally the text from each .txt file would occupy one cell in column a. Any idea why the text would have written so unpredictably?

Comment: You may post some example content and the result excel file, so that others may help.